# Fill the array in Matlab Script, only in one column

Tags: arrays, matlab, fill

How can I fill the array with values that user gave me, in one column need be from smaller to higher number, and in the second column need be from higher to smaller. Than display it. It needs looks like this for example:

tab

1 3

2 2

3 1

```
clear all;    
close all;
a = input('give a value ');
n = input('give n value ');
for (x=1:n-a)
tab = ;
end
```

I really don't idea how to do this, can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your `input` statements, try something like this:

```
tab = [a:n; n:-1:a].';
```

Say `n=3` and `a=1`, then you get the array you show in your question. For `n=5` and `a=2`, you get what your comment requests.

Comment: Thank U! But almost, this need be that value between 2 and 5, for example
2 3 4 5 and other one 5 4 3 2   (dont know why i cannot put this vertical in answers)